# Java GUI hides windows taskbar

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am using `JFrame` to create my GUI for a desktop application.  The size of the GUI I am setting according to the resolution of the platform screen using this code.

```
this.setSize(this.getToolkit().getScreenSize());
```

The problem is that when I run the application the GUI covers all of the screen. The Windows task-bar is also hidden behind the GUI.

I want that whatever the size of the task-bar is, the task-bar should be visible in all conditions.  How do I achieve that?

Comment: "I am _suing_ JFrame"...LOL

Comment: 5 people thought that was a great comment, yet none of them had the rep. to edit the question?

Comment: @Andrew, Apparently some people are just here for the lulz - chill.

Comment: Humor should be left not edited. I enjoyed the laugh

Comment: @All i just realized that i wrote "suing", a spell mistake. ;) enjoyed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about ?

```
jFrame.setState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

Comment: @Hunter lots of methods are still accesible just from java.awt.Frame

Comment: I wasn't saying you couldn't use it. You can use whatever you want, but you should be consistent. So if you are going to use `setState()` from the java.awt.Frame class, then you should use `Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH`. I don't think you should mix the two.

Comment: that's about reading API `Methods inherited from class java.awt.Xxx` http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html

Comment: @mKorbel I am confused by what you said. What is about reading the API?

Comment: @Hunter McMillen, lots of methods are nested and inherited from java.awt.Frame, and if you derive JFrame that some methods/Components are accesible just from java.awt.Frame, same for lots of java.swing.Jxxx too, and in normal programing you never ever needed to define java.awt.Frame#methodsName, only by methodsName

Comment: The only valid values for setState are ICONIFIED and NORMAL.  Calling it with MAXIMIZED_BOTH results in a no-op.

Answer (score 7):

Since you are using a JFrame you should just call:

`jFrame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);`

This takes into account the position of the taskbar.

Comment: What is it doing when you call this? Is it covering the taskbar?

Comment: yes this is covering all the screen, i just want my GUI should work in all screen resolution, thats why i am setting GUI size according to platform screen,  i think i should set hardcoded fized size ..should i?

Comment: Hmm, using `JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH` should take into account the taskbar, it does on my machine atleast.

Comment: :+1 :) it is not working on my Machine, i think i should get screen insets and the set my GUI size according to that.

Comment: K, sorry that didn't work. I just read @harper89s link and it seems to be an alternate way, try that.

Answer (score 5):

Is your task-bar set to auto-hide?

I just ran this test code on my Windows 7 machine.

```
import java.awt.Frame;
import javax.swing.*;

class TestFrameSize {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame f = new JFrame("Test Screen Size");
                f.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                System.out.println(f.getToolkit().getScreenSize());
                f.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
                f.setVisible(true);
                System.out.println(f.getSize());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In fact, I ran it twice.  Here is the output:

### Task-bar configured to 'auto-hide'

```
java.awt.Dimension[width=1920,height=1080]
java.awt.Dimension[width=1928,height=1088]
```

(In which the frame seems to be 8 pixels taller & wider than the available screen space - odd.)

### Task-bar *not* configured to 'auto-hide'

```
java.awt.Dimension[width=1920,height=1080]
java.awt.Dimension[width=1928,height=1048]
```

40 pixels shorter, and no longer covering the task-bar.

Comment: +1 for experimental data. A similar height change obtains with hiding the Mac OS X dock, although the width remains constant.

Comment: I get similar results.  Then I added 'f.setUndecorated(true);' after your first System.out.  The result is the same two identical Dimensions (and a full screen window covering the task bar)

Comment: @Bryan Maybe you should ask a separate question based on that specific requirement.

Comment: Good idea. It might not be as closely related to this as I thought. - [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7403584/does-jframe-setextendedstatemaximized-both-work-with-undecorated-frames)

Answer (score 5):

I know this is old question but when i use `jFrame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);` or the `setState` it displays it properly while displaying it for the first time. When I minimize it and again maximize it, it again covers the Task Bar. I am using Windows 7 and Java 1.7.

I found the solution [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/344387/GUI/java/Maximising-frame-fullscreen-start)

```
f.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);  
GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();  
f.setMaximizedBounds(env.getMaximumWindowBounds());  
f.setVisible(true);
```

this should do the trick.

Answer (score 4):

you should be able to find the TaskbarHeight with a method

say `getTaskbarHeight();`

the minus that from

```
setFullScreen();
```

I found this example online

[Setting screen size - taskBar](http://www.esblog.in/2010/09/setting-swing-window-to-full-screen/)

Comment: this solution doesn't take into consideration multiple monitors, or the task bar being docked on the sides of the screen.  Adding logic for the width isn't a big deal, but I don't see a good way to determine which screen the frame is on.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you shoud use GraphicsDevice.setFullScreenWindow() instead of setFullScreen().
It will maximize a window as opposed to using the screen fully in a "sort-of" non windowed mode.

Comment: that is for full screen exclusive mode.  He wants to maximize the window with the task bar showing.

Answer (score 3):

It is quite a lot easier than all this! The taskbar exists in the insets of the screen. So to get the space you want to occupy just use the results of the following two calls:

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenInsets(f.getGraphicsConfiguration())
```

and

```
f.getGraphicsConfiguration().getBounds();
```

where `f` is a window on the same screen as the taskbar.

Do not use Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize(); because it will give you the size of the first screen but not necessarily the screen you are on.

Try playing around with the below frame while you

- move the window from one screen to another
- drag the task-bar from one edge to another of each screen
- resize the task-bar
- make the task-bar autohide
- adjust your screen resolution.

Each time you press the button it will faithfully print out everything you need to known about the task-bar's position.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class TaskBarExplorer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Frame f = new JFrame("F");
        JButton b = new JButton("do");
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                print("current device");
                print(f.getGraphicsConfiguration());

                GraphicsDevice[] gds = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices();
                print("");
                print("all devices");
                for (GraphicsDevice gd : gds) {
                    print(gd.getDefaultConfiguration());
                }
                print("");
            }
        });
        f.add(b);
        f.setSize(100, 100);
        f.setLocation(600, 400);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
    private static void print(GraphicsConfiguration gc) {
        print("insets: " + Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenInsets(gc));
        print("bounds: " + gc.getBounds());
    }
    private static void print(String s) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }

}
```

Some example output for the lazy (this is from one execution, button pressed after different adjustments):

```
current device
insets: java.awt.Insets[top=0,left=0,bottom=78,right=0]
bounds: java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=0,width=1280,height=1024]

all devices
insets: java.awt.Insets[top=0,left=0,bottom=78,right=0]
bounds: java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=0,width=1280,height=1024]
insets: java.awt.Insets[top=0,left=0,bottom=0,right=0]
bounds: java.awt.Rectangle[x=1280,y=0,width=800,height=600]

current device
insets: java.awt.Insets[top=0,left=0,bottom=0,right=0]
bounds: java.awt.Rectangle[x=1280,y=0,width=800,height=600]

all devices
insets: java.awt.Insets[top=0,left=0,bottom=78,right=0]
bounds: java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=0,width=1280,height=1024]
insets: java.awt.Insets[top=0,left=0,bottom=0,right=0]
bounds: java.awt.Rectangle[x=1280,y=0,width=800,height=600]

current device
insets: java.awt.Insets[top=0,left=0,bottom=0,right=58]
bounds: java.awt.Rectangle[x=1280,y=0,width=800,height=600]

all devices
insets: java.awt.Insets[top=0,left=0,bottom=0,right=0]
bounds: java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=0,width=1280,height=1024]
insets: java.awt.Insets[top=0,left=0,bottom=0,right=58]
bounds: java.awt.Rectangle[x=1280,y=0,width=800,height=600]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me in Windows 10/Java 8:

```
setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();  
setSize(env.getMaximumWindowBounds().getSize());
```