# Auto-Hide Task-Bar and maximum screen space

Tags: java, swing

It is well documented that code like the following

```
    final Rectangle bounds = device.getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds();
    final Insets screenInsets = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenInsets(
        device.getDefaultConfiguration());

    bounds.x = screenInsets.left;
    bounds.y = screenInsets.top;
    bounds.width -= screenInsets.left + screenInsets.right;
    bounds.height -= screenInsets.top + screenInsets.bottom;
```

where `device` is some valid `GraphicsDevice` gives a rectangle that should be the maximum allowable for a device.  There are also other ways which all seem to suffer a shortcoming. For a primary display on MS Windows if the **task-bar is NOT auto-hide** this works.  However if the **task-bar is auto-hide** it will not. I could allow for this in my unit test if I knew how to get the 'right' size or how, in the worst case, to determine when the task-bar is auto-hide then skip this part of the the test.  Googling and Stackoverflowing has not helped.  I know someone can and I thank you in advance!

As Always...

Comment: What exactly happens when the taskbar auto-hides?

Comment: In addition to what Bombe mentioned, I have a Win 7 OS with auto-hide enabled, so test code (and by that I mean an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html) as opposed to uncompilable code snippets) would be a lot more useful.

Comment: See also this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6790600/java-gui-hides-windows-taskbar/6791978#6791978).

Answer (score 1):

if I understood correctly [Full-Screen Exclusive Mode](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/exclusivemode.html), then your window's covered all screen size, including required area for Windows Taskbar (Auto-hide), I don't know correct way how to determine Windows Taskbar#HEIGHT, in all cases, because these heights depends of Applied Themes too, or not

1) (very ugly way) lets some empty space on display's bottom,

2) change Aplication window to the `JFrame`, then TaskBar overlay bottom part of `JFrame`, but you have to lost FullScreenExclusiveMode, that's window as any other

3) change Aplication window to the un-decorated `JDialog`, or JWindow (un-decorated by defalut, but required existence for JFrame, sure never visible, just required as parent) 
NOTICE: try to avoids usage of [JDialog#setModal(true)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.html#setModal%28boolean%29), because TaskBar would be again non-accesible, but in this case you can/have to play with [JDialog#setModalityType](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.html#setModalityType%28java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType%29), quasi to simulated FullScreenExclusiveMode, but Auto-Hide TaskBar could by accesible and overlay bottom of JDialog, but your window couldn't be moved toBack() or iconified()