# Does JFrame.setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH) work with undecorated frames?

Tags: java, winapi, swing

The following Swing code doesn't work correctly on my machine or my co-workers machines (all Windows XP & Java 6):

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Maximize") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                frame.setExtendedState((frame.getExtendedState() & Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH) == Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH ? JFrame.NORMAL : JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
            }
        }));
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

It maximizes the window, but does not take into consideration the windows task bar (it fills the screen).  If you comment out "frame.setUndecorated(true);" it seems to work correctly.

The Javadoc seems to imply this should work.  Is this a bug in Java?  Is it limited to a specific release, or version of Windows?  Is there a workaround?

I've seen a [few workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6790600/java-gui-hides-windows-taskbar/6790670#comment-8891452), but they seem incomplete.  I can't be the first person to code my own frame decorations in Java.

**EDIT:** After downloading the OpenJDK and digging through the native code, I found that Java is calling the win32 function [SetWindowPlacement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633544(v=vs.85).aspx) and under some conditions altering [MINMAXINFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632605(v=vs.85).aspx) to get the right window size.  I think what I was seeing was the default windows behavior for a window with no title or border (although I can't find that documented anywhere).  I've found that calling JFrame.setMaximizedBounds() provides the bounds used to alter the win32 MINMAXINFO structure.  So by altering my action performed and using the window size suggested by camickr as my MaximizedBounds, I get a bit closer:

```
GraphicsConfiguration graphicsConfiguration = frame.getGraphicsConfiguration();
frame.setMaximizedBounds(graphicsConfiguration.getBounds());
frame.setExtendedState((frame.getExtendedState() & Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH) == Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH ? JFrame.NORMAL : JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

Now the maximize window no longer hides the menubar.  But.. now I have another problem.  I can't maximize from a secondary monitor. The frame just disappears.

I'm adding some win32 tags in hopes of getting a C++ programmer who recognizes this problem.

**SOLUTION:** I apparently can't answer my own question yet, so I'll just put my solution here.  I had to use a Sun class, and I haven't tested it on any platforms other than Windows, but so far this seems to be working well with multiple monitors, and multiple taskbar configurations:

```
GraphicsConfiguration config = frame.getGraphicsConfiguration();
Rectangle usableBounds = SunGraphicsEnvironment.getUsableBounds(config.getDevice());
frame.setMaximizedBounds(new Rectangle(0, 0, usableBounds.width, usableBounds.height));
frame.setExtendedState((frame.getExtendedState() & Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH) == Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH ? JFrame.NORMAL : JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

Comment: there are lots of threads about, http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/exclusivemode.html , on this forum

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not trying to make a full screen app.  I probably should have been more clear about my goals, but I'm trying to replace the operating system titlebar and controlls with my own (like Google Chrome, Microsoft Office, etc).  Sun even attempted to do this out of the box once, but they have the same problem I do: `frame.getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.FRAME);`

Answer (score 5):

Interesting. When I try it it seems to happen in two steps. First expands to fill the space above the task bar, then a split second later it covers the task bar. I have no idea why.

Anyway for a workaround you can use:

```
GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
Rectangle bounds = env.getMaximumWindowBounds();
System.out.println("Screen Bounds: " + bounds );
```

to manually set the bounds of your frame when you want to maximize it.

Comment: That seems to get me closer, but setting the bounds of the frame resets the extended state to 'normal'. I could create my own frame subclass and keep track of my own extended state and previous bounds, but the operating system isn't aware of this simulated state, and would betray me in subtle little ways.  In addition, I would need to find some way to get the window bounds on multiple monitors.

Comment: That was the idea to track the bounds and state yourself. I don't know what the subtle problems might be I can't offer any more advice there. I"ve never played with it but for multiple monitors you can look at the `GraphicsDevice` class.