# Button that updates text in a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

How can I create a button that updates text in a JFrame?

I am just looking to create a big label that shows a lot of information in text form when I push an update button.

This is not working:

```
public void JFrameTest2() {
     JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(300, 125);
    frame.setUndecorated(true);
    frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(255, 115, 100));
    frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    Dimension scrSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    Insets toolHeight = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenInsets(
            frame.getGraphicsConfiguration());
    frame.setLocation(scrSize.width - frame.getWidth(), scrSize.height
            - toolHeight.bottom - frame.getHeight());
    frame.setVisible(true);

    final JTextArea Text = new JTextArea(""+System.currentTimeMillis()); 
     JButton NewButton2 = new JButton(new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
        public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {

        Text.revalidate();
        Text.repaint();

        }
    }); 
    frame.add(Text);
    frame.add(NewButton2);
}
```

Comment: how is it _not working_?

Comment: What are you trying to do when you click `NewButton2` ?

Comment: When the button is activated, try actually changing the text of the text area...

Comment: You'll also find JFrame#setExtendedState more useful then manually maximising the frame

Comment: @Reimeus It is not updating the time.

Comment: @MadProgrammer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7403584/does-jframe-setextendedstatemaximized-both-work-with-undecorated-frames)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to update the time in the ActionListener. You don't need to call `revalidate` or `repaint` just only `setText()` or `append` if you don't want to delete previous text.

```
final JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(Long.ToString(System.currentTimeMillis())); 
JButton newButton2 = new JButton("Update time");
newButton2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
     @Override
        public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {    
          textArea.setText(Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()));    
        }
});
```

As a side note, follow java code conventions, variables starts with lower case, call `setVisible()` after adding components.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add

```
Text.setText(""+System.currentTimeMillis());
```

inside the actionPerformed callback. Just calling revalidate/repaint will not update the text.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably read up on what [#revalidate()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#revalidate%28%29) and [#repaint()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#repaint%28%29) do. I get the feeling that you've made an incorrect assumption here.

And it's not updating the contents of your text area because you haven't told it to in your actionPerformed method. Assuming that you just want to write out the result of `System.currentTimeMillis()`, just write the following when constructing your JButton.

```
JButton NewButton2 = new JButton(new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
        Text.setText(""+System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
});
```